# What is the most reliable react native map libary that I can use for my project and work for both ios and android

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, react-native, react-native-ios

I am working on a react native app (detached) and I am a bit confused on what library or how do I easily integrate maps on my react native. I went thru documentation on https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/map-view and then they suggest to use https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps but then I read that this module is somehow not compatible with all versions of react native.

Do you know any library that you can suggest me for maps that works for both IOS and Android?

Comment: you can use https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl for more custom styling and Offline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Airbnb's maps are the most reliable you can use, I have used it in Carpooling project and lots more. It may have some issues, but you can always fix them. Its not like you will get stuck anywhere.